# "Cannot use .this" error when using _ for multiple type parameters in method declaration

Tags: go, generics

I am playing around with type parameters (generics) using Go `1.18beta1`.

## Problem

Consider the following snippet:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    foo := &Foo[string, int]{
        valueA: "i am a string",
        valueB: 123,
    }
    fmt.Println(foo)
}

type Foo[T1 any, T2 any] struct {
    valueA T1
    valueB T2
}

func (f *Foo[_,_]) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%v %v", f.valueA, f.valueB)
}
```

This snippet fails to build with the following error:

```
<autogenerated>:1: cannot use .this (type *Foo[string,int]) as type *Foo[go.shape.string_0,go.shape.string_0] in argument to (*Foo[go.shape.string_0,go.shape.int_1]).String
```

I attempted to use `_` in the method declaration because of the following statement in the [Type Parameters Proposal](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/refs/heads/master/design/43651-type-parameters.md#generic-types):

> The type parameters listed in a method declaration need not have the same names as the type parameters in the type declaration. In particular, if they are not used by the method, they can be _.

## Question

Is the build error above a bug in `1.18beta1` or am I missing something?

## Snippet variations that build successfully

### Use type parameter names

I can make the code build successfully if I change the `String` method declaration to the following (replace the `_` with actual type parameters):

```golang
func (f *Foo[T1,T2]) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%v %v", f.valueA, f.valueB)
}
```

### Single type parameter

I managed to use the `_` successfully when only using a single type parameter:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    foo := &Foo[string]{"i am a string"}

    fmt.Println(foo)
}

type Foo[T1 any] struct {
    value T1
}

func (f *Foo[_]) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%v", f.value)
}
```

### Instantiate Foo with same type for T1 and T2

`_` also works in method declaration if `Foo` is instantiated with the same type (e.g. `string` for both `T1` and `T2`):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    foo := &Foo[string, string]{
        valueA: "i am a string",
        valueB: "i am also a string",
    }
    fmt.Println(foo)
}

type Foo[T1 any, T2 any] struct {
    valueA T1
    valueB T2
}

func (f *Foo[_,_]) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%v %v", f.valueA, f.valueB)
}
```

Comment: I think you found a bug. I couldn't find a similar one in Go GitHub issues: https://github.com/golang/go/issues?q=is%3Aissue+%22cannot+use+.this%22+. By the way, I could compile and run the problematic snippet by replacing one of the" _" with "T".

Comment: Please, let me know if you are not going to report it. I'll do that then.

Comment: Thank you for confirming! I have reported the issue: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/50419

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments of the question, the described behavior is a bug in Go 1.18beta1 and is being tracked by [issue 50419](http://github.com/golang/go/issues/50419).

## Edit

I have confirmed that the bug in question is fixed in [1.18beta2](https://go.dev/blog/go1.18beta2), which was released on 31 January, 2022.